# Get the users with latest conversation(message) first then other without conversation from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have one confusion in mysql query.I have two tables for messages and users so i want result like the users with the latest conversation first and then other users.I am stuck at this point.so anyone can help? 
Currently i have this query but it is only for the users with the conversation exists.

```
select * from (SELECT DISTINCT IF( from_id = $user_id, to_id, from_id ) AS uid,u.display_name,u.username,(SELECT count(*) from user_online uo where uo.user_id = u.id) as online,um.message,um.add_dt
FROM  `user_messages` um INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=IF( from_id = $user_id, to_id, from_id )
WHERE  (to_id = $user_id OR `from_id` = $user_id)

ORDER BY  `add_dt` DESC )tbl GROUP BY uid ORDER BY `add_dt` DESC LIMIT $offset,$records
```

Schema

### users

id,
email,
username,
fb_id,
display_name,
about_me,
password,

### user_messages

id, 
from_id,
to_id,
message,
add_dt, 
deleted,
is_read,

### user_online

id, 
user_id, 
user_ip, 
user_agent, 
login_dt,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add your code in sqlfidder?

Comment: you mean **conversation** instead of **conversion**?

Comment: yes sorry for mistake

Comment: Can you please share the schema?

Comment: Show your schema please

Comment: pl see the schema in question

Comment: Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get, or better yet an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: I want the users who chat with me recently first and after other users who not chat with me also 
for e.g my user id is 1 
uid | displayname | username  | online | message | add_dt
2       abc                  abc              1           hi             2016-06-28 10:00:40
3       xyz                  xyz               0           hello        2016-06-28 10:00:40
4       pqr                  pqr               0           ' '             ' '

Comment: Is `add_dt` message time?

Comment: yes message added date

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your logic a bit.

In derived table `conversations` I have joined `messages` with `online users` and put the `limit` inside, because after all you are limiting `conversations`.

Then I joined the results to `users` table to get only those users which are in `conversations`. Preventing expensive joins.

```
SELECT 
    IF(conversations.uid IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS `isConversation`, 
    conversations.`online`, 
    (SELECT message FROM user_messages WHERE id = conversations.message_id) as `message`, -- get message
    conversations.add_dt, 
    u.id AS uid, 
    u.display_name, 
    u.username 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        IF( um.from_id = $user_id, um.to_id, um.from_id ) AS uid,
        IF(user_id is not null, 1, 0) AS `online`   -- online status
        MAX(um.id) AS `message_id`, -- get latest message id to get message
        MAX(um.add_dt) AS `add_dt` -- get last message time for the particular user
    FROM user_messages um 
        LEFT JOIN user_online uo
        ON uo.user_id = IF( um.from_id = $user_id, um.to_id, um.from_id )
    WHERE 
        ( um.to_id = $user_id OR um.from_id = $user_id )
    GROUP BY -- group by uid
        uid
    ORDER BY    -- sort by latest message
        add_dt DESC 
    LIMIT   -- limit the conversations
        0, 15
) AS conversations
LEFT JOIN users u   -- to get all users
ON conversations.uid = u.id
ORDER BY
    `isConversation` DESC
LIMIT   -- limit the users
    0, 15
```

Update:

I have added a column `isConversation` to check whether it is a conversation, and then sorted by it so all conversation will be on top and then the users without conversations.

Comment: Thanks for answer
But i also want users which are not in conversation after getting all the users which are in conversation so if you can help more?

Comment: A slight change would require, convert JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I am getting older message from the user but i want latest message from the user.

Comment: Ok, everything else is fine?

Comment: Still i am getting oldest message from the user that i need to change to latest from that conversation

Comment: Can you pl help for get latest message i have tried but not getting result?